# How to add required argument with optional flag

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a differ. The command line needs to handle two files - left and right. I would like the synapsis to be like this:

```
differ.py [-f] FILE1 [[-t] FILE2]
```

WHERE `-f` is the option that accepts FILE1, `-t` accepts FILE2.
FILE1 is mandatory, FILE2 can be read from stdin or real file. I would like it to be used like this:

```
differ.py myfile1
differ.py myfile1 myfile2
differ.py myfile1 -t myfile2
differ.py -f myfile1
differ.py -f myfile1 myfile2
differ.py -f myfile1 -t myfile2
```

Is it possible with `argparse` module? If so, then how?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "WHERE -f is the option that accepts FILE1" - that doesn't make sense. Is `FILE1` a positional argument or an option value? It can't be both.

Comment: if `FILE1` is mandatory argument why to parse it and declare it as optional argument?
did you read the argparse module [argparse_link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#module-argparse)?

Comment: @Adam it's not an optional argument. It's mandatory, but I'd prefer `-f` string to be optional.

Comment: Possble, maybe, but awkward.  What's the point to using these '-t' and '-f' flags?  They don't add any information, do they?

Comment: What happens if someone does `differ.py -t myfile2 myfile1`, or `differ.py myfile2 -f myfile1`?

Comment: Thanks for all the input, I'll reconsider and redesign it taking your valuable info into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible through `argparse`. It goes against too much of the design. An argument can't be *both* a positional argument and an option value, and which positional argument a positional argument is doesn't depend on the presence or position of options. You can't even work around any of this with mutually exclusive groups, because a positional argument can't be part of such a group. The help formatter isn't designed for any of this, either.

Even if you moved all the validation and help formatting out of `argparse` and into your own code, you'd be overriding so much and getting so little out of `argparse` that it'd be easier to just parse the command line manually.

If this is really the interface you want, it'll be easiest to parse `sys.argv` manually.